# create scaled images in xml in android

Tags: android, scale, android-linearlayout

I have 5 images that I want to place in image buttons inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`. The images are saved in different sizes on the disk, but when placed in the layout, I want them to be of the same height, but in different weights of 0.5,1,1,1,0.5 (meaning the  weight sum of the layout is 4). I tryed using this code and it didn't work:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scrollLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/left"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dog"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fish"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cat"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scrollRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/right"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Are there any parameters of `layout_width` and `layout_height` that I can change that will get this to work, or do I need to create a scaled bitmap from java code for each one of the buttons?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try defining the same height and then you scaling to keep the ratio

```
<ImageView
    .... 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    .... />
```

**EDIT** using a `match_parent`for the height will make the `ImageButtons` have the same height and keep the scale ratio using `scaleType`

Comment: That'll be problematic, as I want the images to fit correctly for all phone sizes..

Comment: definitely if you want to have the same height and keep the ratio at the same time you'll have to change the width too

Comment: Thanks! It looks better, but it doesn't increase the size of the images. Is there a way to do that too? Now I just have a small image in the middle of the button

Comment: it'll be hard to keep the same height and ratio since this requires the sum of the images' width to not be greater than the screen's width